# In terms of spherical coordinates describe the following solids

Tags: calculus

In terms of spherical coordinates describe  the following solids:

(i)  Inside the sphere $ \ x^2+y^2+z^2=16 \  $ and above the plane $ \ z=3 \ $

(ii) Between the spheres $ \ x^2+y^2+z^2=5 \ $ and $ x^2+y^2+z^2=3 \ $

**Answer:**

(i)

The spherical coordinate is

$ \begin{eqnarray}
x &=& \rho \sin \theta \cos\phi \\
y &=& \rho \sin \theta \sin\phi \\
z &=& \rho \cos \theta
\end{eqnarray} $

The **description** is given below:

$ \frac{3}{\cos \phi} \leq \rho  \leq 4 \\ 0 \leq \phi \leq \pi \\ 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi \ $

(ii)

**I can not describe the same ranges for  the second case.**

Help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

For the first check the bound for $\phi $

$ \frac{3}{\cos \phi} \leq \rho  \leq 4 \\ \color{red}{0 \leq \phi \leq {pi}}\\ 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi \ $

For the second simply

$ \sqrt 3 \leq \rho  \leq \sqrt 5 \\ 0 \leq \phi \leq \pi \\ 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi \ $

Comment: what should be the bound for $ \ \phi \ $  for first part? I think $ \ 0 \leq \phi \leq \pi \ $ Is not it ?

Comment: @yourmath the plane x-z (y=0) then the intersection between the line $z=3$ and $x^2+z^2=16$ we find $x=\pm \sqrt 7$ then $\pi_{max}=\arctan \frac{\sqrt 7}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{3} \leq \rho  \leq \sqrt{5}$
$0 \leq \phi \leq \pi$
$0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

--- rk